# Phpmyadmin blank screen, crypt_aes not found

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Im setting up a centos 6.6 server with apache php **mysql** and phpmyadmin.

But whenever i'm logging in to phpmyadmin i get a blank screen. In the log i found this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Crypt_AES' not found in
>   /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php
>   on line 648, referer: http://IP/phpmyadmin/

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Did you download phpMyAdmin directly or use the package manager? What versions of phpMyAdmin, PHP, and MySQL do you have?